# How to change the home screen wallpaper randomly

Tags: shortcuts-app, ios

How can I set to change my iPhone's wallpaper automatically? I have an album called wallpapers and I want these wallpapers set as wallpapers on my home screen randomly.

I'm using iOS 13 and interested on some tweaks with shortcuts more than third party apps. If there are any third party app for this, those are also welcome.

Comment: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2019/07/how-change-iphone-wallpaper-daily-shortcuts.html but one of the widgets is not available for ios 13

Comment: There is an iPhone app named Vellum Wallpapers that supposedly supplies the images and changes it everyday. It's available on the ios App store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 13.1.2 there is no default way of doing this. However, a Photos & Video *action* called **Set wallpaper to** will be available in future for use with the Shortcuts app.

This action will allow users to set the Wallpaper for either their Lock Screen or Home Screen from a Photos album (which is what you're looking for) or from an online source.

I will update this answer once that action is available for the Shortcuts app.

In the meantime there are a number of apps available on the App Store that promise to change your Wallpaper. Some examples follow:

- [Shuffle Wallpapers](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shuffle-wallpapers/id1225466765)
- [Vellum Wallpapers](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/vellum-wallpapers/id1095068317)
- [Wallpapers & Backgrounds: HD](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wallpapers-backgrounds-hd/id1198467809)
- [Wallpapers & Background Themes](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wallpapers-background-themes/id1044527592)
- [Live Wallpapers Now](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/live-wallpapers-now/id1098805023)

However, my understanding is that most apps use an online resource (a library of wallpapers) from where the wallpapers are downloaded. You'd need to check if any of them allow you to use a locally stored Photos album as your wallpaper source.

**Disclaimer:** I have not used any of the apps listed above, nor do I have an association with any of the developers. You will need to determine if any of them meets your needs and what cost, if any, they have.

Comment: now any of the above apps cant change the backgrounds automatically

Comment: That's a bummer. I'm really hoping Apple enables the *Set wallpaper to* action in Shortcuts sooner rather than later. This can be used as part of a Shortcut (with other actions) to do exactly what you (and many others) would love to do.